# Как недопускать выхода input за границу блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая разметка:

```css
body {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}
header {
 top: 0;
 
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 640px;
 margin:0px auto;
 position: fixed;
   z-index: 999;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .06);
   background: blue;
}

header .header {
 padding: 10px;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-areas:
  "search menu"
 ;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

#headerSearchDiv form input[type="text"] {
 padding: 8px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 2px solid yellow;
 font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <div class="header">
                <div id="headerSearchDiv">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Поиск">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

получается так что input превышает ширину header. Как этого избежать? но только чтобы input был на всю ширину.

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box;`

Comment: @andreymal а куда это добавить нужно?

Comment: К стилям инпута

Comment: @andreymal большое спасибо! это помогло)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#headerSearchDiv input[type="text"] {box-sizing: border-box;}
```